# Unity dynamic texture changing

Tags: c#, textures, mesh, unity-game-engine

I've build the model in blender3d and imported it into my unity project in fbx.  The model contains two materials. After that I'm trying to change the texture of the `materials[1].mainTexture`:

```
texs = Resources.LoadAll("", typeof(Texture2D));
photos.GetComponent<Renderer> ().materials[1].mainTexture = (Texture2D)texs[10];
```

In editor mode all seems to be good but when I'm building the app the model doesn't render. I've already found out that if I'm not changing the texture everything renders fine.

How could I fix that problem?

Comment: I could change textures in an old project of mine by using byte arrays. Create a texture variable and set it by tex.LoadImage() method.

Answer (score 0):

Loading all `Texture2D` resources in the game and then setting the second material's `mainTexture` to the 11-th texture in those loaded ressources seems a bit risky. If you add more `Texture2D`s to the project / that texture folder, the indexes could change. Also, maybe `Resources.LoadAll` doesn't guarantee you the ordering you expected (could be different in Debug mode and Release mode). If you already have a static index of `10` in that collection of textures, you should just declare it to be a static (or just `public Texture2D` in regards to the script and assign it in the inspector, i.e. fixate the texture you want to apply.

Comment: I won't add any more textures. The problem is in changing mainTexture. I've tried to get texture from public Texture2D and set it as mainTexture but it also gave me no result.

Comment: If you set `photos.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[1].mainTexture = someTexture;` whereas there's a `public Texture2D someTexture;` in the script and this doesn't change the texture, you're doing something wrong. You should start debugging by logging some values about what material you assigning to and what the target texture is.

Comment: It does, but only in editor mode. After the build everything goes wrong

Comment: Strange bug. This is probably not Unity's fault, it should be able to load the texture (`Resources.Load()`) and assign it to the material in the editor and in a built game. You should try loading a texture from resources and assigning it as a material texture in a small, isolated project to see that that works.  (i.e. create a minimum, complete, verifiable example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ]). Otherwise it's a side effect from something else.

Comment: I'd better try to install newer version of unity and try to build my project from there. Thanks for advices